# How do I escape string on mysql using triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers, escaping, database-trigger

I need to store queries on another table and backup them, it works fine until some double quote (`"`) or single quote (`'`) comes in column values so it messes the query when I do a backup.

I have created an Insert before trigger on mysql

```
BEGIN
    SET @col_names_str = 'option_id , option_name , option_value , autoload';
    SET @col_vals_str = CONCAT('"', NEW.option_id, '"', ',', '"', NEW.option_name, '"', ',', '"', NEW.option_value, '"', ',', '"', NEW.autoload, '"');
    SET @cur_query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO `wp_options` ', '(', @col_names_str, ')', ' VALUES ', '(', @col_vals_str, ')', ';');
    INSERT INTO wp_query_recorder (id, query, table_name) VALUES (NULL, @cur_query, 'wp_options');
END
```

I want to escape the value of the column before inserting into another table.

For example data like this

```
"O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:12:"last_checked";i:1519369979;}"
```

to this

```
'O:8:\"stdClass\":1:{s:12:\"last_checked\";i:1519369919;}'
```

Something like this  `esc_sql(NEW.option_value)` , is this possible to do?

Comment: Are you trying to protect against SQL Injection? This is absolutely not possible using mysql in triggers. It's already too late, MySQL interpreted as something else. Please don't do this for security and fix your actual security problem.

Comment: No its not to avoid security issues i want to log these queries and need to import and export them. it makes mess with import because of those quotes

Comment: Maybe use another mechanism. MySQL has query log features?

Comment: its self hosted product, should work on all shared hosting. i dont think so query logs accessable in all shared hostings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [QUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) function.

Comment: exactly what I wanted.